# Android if no checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox

I need your help. I have several checkboxes and I want when no checkbox is checked to display a message informing the user to choose at least 1 checkbox by the Toast view. Here is my code, now if no checkbox is checked it displays the message but after that it displays the other message.

```
if(ketch.isChecked()==true){

                    result2.append("Ketchup"+"\n");
                }
                if(may.isChecked()==true){

                    result2.append("Mayonnaise"+"\n");
                }
                if(mus.isChecked()==true){

                    result2.append("Mustard"+"\n");
                }
                else{


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose at least 1 topping!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }




Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+name.getText()+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone.getText()+"\n"+"Address: " +address.getText()+"\n"+"Shape: "+sh.getText()+"\n"+"Cheese: "+ty.getText()+"\n"+"Toppings: "+"\n"+result.toString()+"Sauce: "+"\n"+result2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Just saying: `if (may.isChecked())` is the same as `if (may.isChecked()==true)`

Answer (score 1):

Use else if

```
if(ketch.isChecked()){

                result2.append("Ketchup"+"\n");
            }
            else if(may.isChecked()){

                result2.append("Mayonnaise"+"\n");
            }
            else if(mus.isChecked()){

                result2.append("Mustard"+"\n");
            }
            else{


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose at least 1 topping!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+name.getText()+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone.getText()+"\n"+"Address: " +address.getText()+"\n"+"Shape: "+sh.getText()+"\n"+"Cheese: "+ty.getText()+"\n"+"Toppings: "+"\n"+result.toString()+"Sauce: "+"\n"+result2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Pure java!

Comment: when I use if else I have to check all the checkboxes.. I want to check at least one

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
boolean atLeastOneChecked = false;

if(ketch.isChecked()==true){

    result2.append("Ketchup"+"\n");
    atLeastOneChecked = true;
}
if(may.isChecked()==true){

    result2.append("Mayonnaise"+"\n");
    atLeastOneChecked = true;
}
if(mus.isChecked()==true){

    result2.append("Mustard"+"\n");
    atLeastOneChecked = true;
}

if (!atLeastOneChecked)
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose at least 1 topping!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else 
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+name.getText()+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone.getText()+"\n"+"Address: " +address.getText()+"\n"+"Shape: "+sh.getText()+"\n"+"Cheese: "+ty.getText()+"\n"+"Toppings: "+"\n"+result.toString()+"Sauce: "+"\n"+result2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create List checkboxesList and put all CheckBoxes there then you can create your method like this :

```
public boolean isAnyCheckboxChecked() {
    for(Checkbox chekbox : checkboxesList)
       if(checkbox.isChecked())
          return true;
    return false;
}
```

It could be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

More cleaner way of implementing it

```
    if(ketch.isChecked())
    {
        result2.append("Ketchup"+"\n");
    }
    else if(may.isChecked())
    {
        result2.append("Mayonnaise"+"\n");
    }
    else if(mus.isChecked())
    {
        result2.append("Mustard"+"\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose at least 1 topping!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+name.getText()+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone.getText()+"\n"+"Address: " +address.getText()+"\n"+"Shape: "+sh.getText()+"\n"+"Cheese: "+ty.getText()+"\n"+"Toppings: "+"\n"+result.toString()+"Sauce: "+"\n"+result2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ketch.isChecked()==true){
    result2.append("Ketchup"+"\n");
}
if(may.isChecked()==true){
    result2.append("Mayonnaise"+"\n");
}
if(mus.isChecked()==true){
    result2.append("Mustard"+"\n");
}

if(!(ketch.isChecked() || may.isChecked() || mus.isChecked())){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose at least 1 topping!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: "+name.getText()+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone.getText()+"\n"+"Address: " +address.getText()+"\n"+"Shape: "+sh.getText()+"\n"+"Cheese: "+ty.getText()+"\n"+"Toppings: "+"\n"+result.toString()+"Sauce: "+"\n"+result2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
```